# LINQ join query with relational entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using ef-core 2.1, I have the following simplified entities where one `Account` maps to zero or more `Attribute` objects:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LongId { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

I have an initial collection of strings that resemble an `Attribute.Value` for a given fixed `Attribute.Name`, I want to find a second associated `Attribute` object from the same parent `Account` and obtain its `Attribute.Value`.

I want to left join the ef entities against the initial string collection so I can easily infer:

1. Whether no corresponding `Account` exists or an `Account` exists without the related `Attribute` objects (both equate to the same use case).
2. If an `Account` exists and it contains all the required `Attribute` objects, I want to obtain the value of the secondary `Attribute`.

Without LINQ and ef, I run the following SQL query which ignores the parent `Account` and produces the result set I want:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    id nvarchar(20) not null
);
INSERT INTO #Temp (id) VALUES ('cejawq'), ('issokq'), ('cqlpjq'), ('mbgzvi'), ('wqwlff'), ('iedifh');
SELECT t.[Id], attr2.[Value]
FROM #Temp t
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Attributes] attr1
    ON t.[Id]=attr1.[Value]
    AND attr1.[Name]='uid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Attributes] attr2
    ON attr1.[AccountId]=attr2.[AccountId]
    AND attr2.[Name]='objType';
```

I get the following result set:

```
id|objType
-----------
cejawq|ext
issokq|ext
cqlpjq|int
mbgzvi|int
wqwlff|ext
iedifh|null
```

I am struggling with mapping this to efficient LINQ such that the SQL generated produces the result set remotely and ships back data that I can project to an equivalent anonymous type. Do I need to care about the parent objects in the LINQ case? I don't have an index on the `Attribute.Value` column.

The `Attributes` table contains the following data:

```
Id|Name   |Value |AccountId
1 |uid    |cejawq|1
2 |objType|ext   |1
3 |uid    |issokq|2
4 |objType|ext   |2
5 |uid    |cqlpjq|3
6 |objType|int   |3
7 |uid    |mbgzvi|4
8 |objType|int   |4
9 |uid    |wqwlff|5
10|objType|ext   |5
```

Comment: Please post your dbo.Attributes table for your query sample.

Comment: I have added some sample data that illustrates what the query was leveraging.

Comment: I added the models and data context classes in my answer. I added a property AccountId in Attribute class.

Comment: I noticed while trying to build the query myself that not incorporating the AccountId property was an oversight that made this difficult. I don't have access to my full data set until morning but I plan to give this a whirl asap. Thank you very much for the detailed help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the EF Core does not support joins with in memory sequences (yet), you can split the query in two parts - one which takes the data server side (`[Attributes` to `[Attributes` join) using in memory collection as filter (SQL `IN` through LINQ `Contains` method), and second which performs left join in memory with the result of the db query:

```
DbContext db = ...;
var uids = new [] { "cejawq", "issokq", "cqlpjq", "mbgzvi", "wqwlff", "iedifh" };

var dbQuery =
    from attr1 in db.Set<Attribute>()
    where attr1.Name == "uid" && uids.Contains(attr1.Value)
    join attr2 in db.Set<Attribute>()
    on new { AccountId = attr1.Account.Id, Name = "objType" }
    equals new { AccountId = attr2.Account.Id, attr2.Name }
    into attr2Group from attr2 in attr2Group.DefaultIfEmpty() // left outer join
    select new { uid = attr1.Value, objType = attr2.Value };

var query =
    from uid in uids
    join dbResult in dbQuery on uid equals dbResult.uid
    into dbResultGroup from dbResult in dbResultGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() // left outer join
    select new { uid, dbResult?.objType };

var result = query.ToList();
```

It translates to a single db query like this:

```sql
SELECT [attr1].[Value] AS [uid], [attr2].[Value] AS [objType]
FROM [Attributes] AS [attr1]
LEFT JOIN [Attributes] AS [attr2] ON ([attr1].[AccountId] = [attr2].[AccountId]) AND (N'objType' = [attr2].[Name])
WHERE ([attr1].[Name] = N'uid') AND [attr1].[Value] IN (N'cejawq', N'issokq', N'cqlpjq', N'mbgzvi', N'wqwlff', N'iedifh')
```

Comment: That was brilliant, the query returned a result set from production data instantly. You have been a huge help.